# Using Spark, how can I pickup a filename when loading everything into a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

My code sample looks like this.

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

customSchema = StructType([ \
StructField("asset_id", StringType(), True), \
StructField("price_date", StringType(), True), \
etc., 
StructField("close_price", StringType(), True), \
StructField("filename", StringType(), True)])

fullpath = 'path_to files_and_all_credentials'
```

Now, to get everything in a dataframe, with the file path added as a column, I would expect the code to be something like this...

```
df = spark.load(fullPath, withColumn("filename", input_file_name(), header='false', schema = customSchema, sep='|')
```

or...

```
df = spark.read.format("csv"), \
   .option("header", "false"), \
   .option(schema = customSchema), \
   .option(delimiter = "|"), \
   .load(fullPath), \
   .withColumn("filename", input_file_name()
```

When I run this sample code, I get an 'invalid syntax' error message.  This should be a pretty straightforward thing, I think.  How can I make this work?  Thank you!!

Comment: You forgot a closing parenthesis in the last line. And you don't need commas between the `.option()` calls.

Comment: Ah, great catch!  I finally got it working.  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
   .option("header", "false") \
   .option("sep","|") \
   .schema(customSchema) \
   .load(fullPath) \
   .withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

And, to write to DB.

```
import pandas as pd
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=db_name"
props = {"user": "usr","password": "pwd"}

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
#df.printSchema()
#df.show()

df.write.mode('append').jdbc(url,"dbo.table_name",properties=props)
```